# Keep getting BAD_ACCESS when compiling C in Xcode

Tags: c++, c, xcode

If I start a new Command Line C Project in Xcode and enter the following code I always get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when compiling the project.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *foo = "Hello";
    *foo = 'M'; // get EXC_BAD_ACCESS here when compiling
}
```

I'm just learning C and can't workout what is wrong with this statement? I'm just trying to change the character at a certain memory location. Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: `foo` points at a string literal. You cannot modify it (the literal, not `foo`.)

Comment: And you don't get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when compiling this code. You get it when *running* it.

Comment: I see, forgot about that.You're right 'char *foo = "Hello";' is not the same as 'char foo[] = "Hello";', Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has undefined behaviour. You are attempting to modify a string literal.

Comment: Thanks, I can see now that I'm trying to change a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

BAD_ACCESS is to Mac what segmentation fault is to Linux. You are corrupting memory. I also assume you get that error during execution, not compiling (because that would be strange).

EDIT:

I would also like to point out that when allocated statically, this will not happen.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char foo[] = "Hello";
    *foo = 'M'; // no more EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
}
```

Comment: Well, you are most likely not corrupting memory since the allocation is most likely in a read-only memory page.

Comment: It's not in read only memory. If call printf("%s\n",foo) the result will me 'Mello '

Comment: Not in your code, in the OP's code.

Comment: No, it is undefined behaviour (in OP's code). You can't expect it to be anything.

Comment: @Zaph oh, sorry, didn't know you meant that.

Comment: My mistake, I should have written "OP" not "you".